# Is Anima a Final Aeon?

Tags: final-fantasy

in *Final Fantasy X* when Yuna's party is going though the old Blitzball Stadium in Zanarkand they see a memory of a mother hinting for her child to choose her to become the Final Aeon. then we see a young Seymour crying saying he doesn't want her to.

However in the Baaj Temple (where Tidas first awoke in Spira and met Rikku) is a Fayth which is revealed to be Seymour's mother who choose to become the Aeon Anima.

So is Anima a Final Aeon? If so why didn't Seymour fight Sin? if not then what happened in Zanarkand that prevented her becoming the Final Aeon but instead a regular Aeon?

Comment: I though final aeon is different for every summoner? for Yuna's father it's Jecht, but Yuna refuse to sacrifice anyone.

Comment: @memor-x is this an anime? It seems like your referring to the game. Have I missed something here?

Comment: @KazRodgers questions on Japanese games are on topic so long as the question is limited to story. some anime like Steins;Gate and Fate/Stay night were originally games and Touhou is primary a game series. however no there is no anime of Final Fantasy X but I wouldn't put it past them not to have released some Novella like they did with Final Fantasy XIII

Comment: @memor-x I wasn't doubting if it was on topic or not. I just thought I missed out on something major in life and my depression was insta-triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anima was indeed the final aeon. As for why Seymour didn't use it, well, Seymour started the pilgrimage when he was still very young with his mother and he was not aware of the final aeon and the final summoning back then. When his mother finally revealed her plan to become the final aeon so for the sake of Seymour, it left him devastated. He broke off the pilgrimage there and didn't proceed any further and thus didn't fight sin. This can be verified from the [wiki](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Seymour%27s_mother) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Anima is his Final Aeon, though he never wanted to challenge Sin until he grew up and realized the power Sin had over Spira. After he realized that he decided he wanted to become Sin, and for that he needed Yuna.

Although, there is an unpopular theory that, because Seymour never completed his Pilgrimage (that much is stated in the temples) his talents were better put to use aiding Spira, rather than journeying.